# How to use Table/Tree in Pencil

Tags: mockups, mockup-tool, evolus-pencil

I am trying to make a mockup using Evolus Pencil, and I'm having trouble with showing the treetable properly. The treetable is shown like this:

[image]

I tried two different ways to show a tree and none of them worked. Here is the code that I used inside the treetable:

```
Kurskode/Gjennomføringer|Kursnavn/Gjennomføringnavn|[ ]Valgt 
[-}Kurs1|Kursnavn1|
[-]Kurs2|Kursnavn2|
    [-]kurs21|kursnavn21|
      [-]Gjennomføringer1|Gjennomføringnavn1|[^]
~Kurs3| Kursnavn3|
~~kurs32|Kursnavn32|
~~kurs33|Kursnavn333|
~~~kurs333|kurs333navn|[]
~~~~Gjennomføring2|Gjennomføringnavn2|[]
~~~~Gjennomføring3|Gjennomføringnavn3|[]
```

Can someone help me on showing the tree nodes and checkbox on 3rd column properly? And are there any documentations/resources for Evolus Pencil?

Thanks!

Comment: From looking at the source for the Table/Tree widget, it only supports simple rows and columns (using newlines and `|`) and not any sort of nesting. It looks like a column heading such as `[] Foo` (no space between the brackets) should make the column a checkbox column, but it's not displaying for me and I'm not sure how you'd then mark individual cells as checked.

Comment: @nathanielw by adding a * to the square brackets the checkbox becomes checked

Comment: @RameshPareek , it works in a "common" table, but not in treetable